# How to do batch update in dynamo db that updates only a specific field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The table consists of the following fields: deviceId, userId, key, validity

This is my code for batch updating

```
TableWriteItems writeItems = new TableWriteItems(getDevicesTableName(manufacturer, sdkType));

for(int j = i * maxUpdatePerBatch; j < (i + 1) * maxUpdatePerBatch; j++)
{
    JSONObject device = devices.getJSONObject(j);

    writeItems.addItemToPut(new Item().with(Param.DEVICE_ID, device.getString(Param.DEVICE_ID))
                                      .with(Param.VALIDITY, device.getString(Param.VALIDITY)));
}

BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = db.batchWriteItem(writeItems);
```

What I am trying to do is just to update the validity field while keeping the value of the fields key and userId.

However, when I execute the code above, it seems to update the validity filed but removing the key and userId fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only batchWriteItem which is the equivalent of putItem which replaces the entire item in the table with the item you specify.

You need to call updateItem individually for each item.

Comment: Wouldn't that take a very long time if I am updating thousands of items?

Comment: You can make the calls in parallel. You are really only limited by your provisioned write capacity and whatever networking/compute limits you have on what is making the update calls.